# Add paddings between closed angular material accordion panels with css or html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm curious how to add padding/margin (spaces) between the panels. Looking for html/css solution.

https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples

any ideas?

```
accordion-payment-panel {
margin-bottom: 10px!important; // won't work
}
```

Answer (score 12):

try add this code in css:

```
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, thank you but unfortunately it doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expanded),
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expansion-panel-spacing) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

link to code in [github](https://github.com/newshahn/mat-accordion-spacing)

Comment: worked great for me. I also removed the .mat-accordion since mine was not wrapped in one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example the material-angular site created and it produces the spacing correctly:

```
 <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
     .....
 </mat-accordion>
```

and then for the .css:

```
.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-title,
.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.example-headers-align .mat-form-field + .mat-form-field {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```